# Apache Virtualhost shows default page only

Tags: virtualhost

I've been struggling with Apache Virtualhost for a day now.
I would like to run 2 sites with one ip.

When I enter the address in the url bar(domain1 or domain2),
it always shows the default page only(which is domain1).

Any help will/would be appreciated...

**My configuration :**

**/var/www/html:**

domain1/public_html/index.html

domain2/public_html/index.html

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled:**

├── domain1.conf -> ../sites-available/domain1.conf

└── domain2.conf -> ../sites-available/domain2.conf

**domain2.conf :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.domain1.tk
    ServerAlias domain1.tk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**domain2.conf :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain2.tk
    ServerAlias www.domain2.tk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**apache2.conf :**

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: Please improve your formatting. And first a dumb question: Did you disable the default site?

Comment: Add the output of `apachectl -S`

Comment: It's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I lookup your domains, I get 2 different IP addresses. In this case your configuration needs to be something like this:

```
# This is the "main" server running on IP_ADDRESS_OF_DOMAIN_tsk-run.tk
ServerAdmin webmaster@tsk-run.tk
ServerName tsk-run.tk
ServerAlias www.tsk-run.tk
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tsk-run/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<VirtualHost IP_ADDRESS_OF_DOMAIN_tsk-test.tk>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@tsk-test.tk
    ServerName tsk-test.tk
    ServerAlias www.tsk-test.tk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tsk-test/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace `IP_ADDRESS_OF_DOMAIN_tsk-test.tk` with the IP address of this domain.

See [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) section `Name-based hosts on more than one IP address` for more details.

Comment: Thank you. It's working now, but it put me on the root('html') page. Anyway, you've helped me a lot already...

Comment: @jan what dou mean with root('html') page?

Comment: I mean I'm in the "Main DocumentRoot('/var/www/html') instead of '/var/www/html/tsk-run.tk/public_html' .

Comment: There was an another mistake by me. The domain was pointing on wrong place. But I couldn't make it without your help. Cheers. :)